# Big O and Running Time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Let's say we have two algorithms that solve the same problem.

Algorithm *A* has *O*(n) running-time complexity, and Algorithm *B* has *O*(n<sup>3</sup>) running-time complexity.

For an input of the size of 1000, *A* takes 1 second, and *B* takes 3 seconds.

Having said that, how long will Algorithms *A* and *B* take for input of size 3000?

My guess is:

- *A* will take 3 seconds, since it is linear (1 second for 1000 size).
- *B* will take 81 seconds, as it is 3 times the size of the original input, which takes 3 seconds (so, 3*3<sup>3</sup>)

Second question: If I were to have an algorithm with running-time complexity *O*(n), and I were to ram up the processor speed and memory size to twice of the original, will the running-time complexity for the algorithm still be the same in Big O, which is *O*(n)?

Please provide an explanation.

Comment: algorithms not shown in question and how did you consider that the running time is n or n^3? not clear what you mean

Comment: @Mr.AF please consider "Let's say" at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how long will Algorithms A and B take for input of size 3000?

If run time for `n==0` is 0 seconds, then the 2 guesses are reasonable predictions.

---

> I were to <strike>ram</strike> ramp up the processor speed ... to twice of the original,

Run times expect to be half, assuming the limiting factor was processor speed and not I/O throughput, etc. but it does not change big(O)

> ... to memory size to twice of the original ...

Again, does not change big (O).  I would not expect a run-time reduction unless the process was memory bound.

Comment: Thanks for an actual answer, to conclude then big O is only affected by algorithm and not hardware then.

Comment: @MatsuzakaSteven . . . This is not true.  The run time can be 0 for 0 rows AND you can still have overhead with lower order contributions to the complexity.  Complexity is simply not sufficient for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little long for a comment.

Big-oh notation is about what happens as the data goes to infinity.  If you have one data point:

```
n=1000, time=1 sec
```

You don't have enough information to generalize.  This could be:

```
per n, 1/1000 seconds, no overhead
per n, 1/1000000 seconds, 0.999 overhead
```

You could also have small factors -- such as sqrt(n) or log(n) in the actual run time.

And for the second algorithm, the situation is more complicated still.

The important thing to remember is that big-O is a *theoretical* measure of algorithmic complexity.  It does not substitute for actually analyzing a specific algorithm on a specific machine

EDIT:

Technically, two functions have the same "big-Oh" when this limit is bounded to a non-`NULL` value:

```
f1(n)
-----  as n --> infinity
f2(n)
```

For convenience, we specify big-Oh using simple functions, such as n^2, log(n), e^n, and so on.

It is only a statement about what happens as the size goes to infinity.  Period.  There are many examples of algorithms with poor complexity that work pretty well  in real-world problems.  For instance, quicksort has a worst-case complexity (hence "complexity") of O(n^2), but works so well in the average case that it is often the sorting algorithm of choice.

Comment: This. Also worth noting that O-notation is usually constant-agnostic

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm asking for the logic on how running-time grows on Big-O, assume it like physics, nothing is perfect and everything differs due to small factors but we still can assume everything as perfect

Comment: @MatsuzakaSteven . . . No.  You cannot assume that everything is perfect.  At least, that would not be part of my understanding of algorithms.  Your question has not provided enough information to make a definitive statement about which algorithm is better -- although there is *circumstantial* evidence that the linear algorithm will perform better.

Comment: The part after "Technically" isn't technically right (even if you limit to strictly positive functions to avoid the divide by zero): "limit converges" should read "lim sup exists", because the limit doesn't necessarily exist. Consider f1(n) = 1+n%2, f2(n) = 2-n%2. Both are O(1) but f1/f2 alternates between 1/2 and 2 so there's no limit. It's possible to come up with examples where f1 and f2 are increasing that have the same problem.

Comment: @PaulHankin . . . I adjusted the language.

Answer (score 0):

All these complexity claims start with a sentence which you have forgotten in your calculations:

> There is a `n0` so that for all `n` greater than `n0` ...

Since you have no info about this `n0` value, you can't draw any conclusions concerning the timing behaviour of the two algorithms.

Just to illustrate this with an example, consider the possibility that the input data set fits into the CPU cache or not. Once it grows too big for the cache, there is usually a large increase in runtime.